# I can't listen any voice in my phone as well as in Web App after receiving the call from twilio

Tags: .net, angular, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have created an application in Angular where the admin calls their user on a phone number, I am using Twilio for this, my frontend is in Angular 14 and my Backend is in .net core API, But when I initiate a call from Web App, I am receiving calls on my phone, but no voice is coming from both side, whereas I can listen to my voice in Twilio console.

```
OnInit(): void {
console.log(this.data);
this.patientName = this.data.patientName;
    this.phoneNumber = this.data.patientPhoneNumber;
    this.patientId = this.data.id;
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    console.log(this.user);
    let self = this;
    console.log(this.data.patientName);
    this.authService.getRequest('audiocall/twilio/token', null).subscribe((data) => {
        try {
            this.device = Twilio.Device.setup(data['data'], {
                debug: false,
                closeProtection: true
            });
            this.setupHandlers(this.device);
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.iserror = false;
                self.callCustomer();
            }, 500);
        } catch (err) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    if (err.error && err.error.message) {
      this.toastr.error(err.error.message);
    }
        }
    });
    }
    setupHandlers(device) {
    let self = this;

    device.on('ready', (_device) => {
        console.log('Ready to call');
    });

    device.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('ERROR: ' + error.message);
        this.iserror = true;
  if (error.error && error.error.message) {
    this.toastr.error(error.error.message);
  }
  this.dialogRef.close()
    });
    device.on('connect', (connection) => {
        console.log(connection);
        if ('patientPhoneNumber' in connection.message) {
            this.callStartTime = new Date();
        }
        if ('patientId' in connection.message) {
            this.callStartTime = new Date();
        }
        this.addCallStatus(connection);
    });

    device.on('disconnect', (connection) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.callEndTime = new Date();
            let formData = {
                'status' : 'COMPLETED',
                'voiceCallLogId' : self.voiceCallLogId,
                'callEndTime' : self.callEndTime,
                'callSid': connection.parameters.CallSid
            }
            self.updateCallStatus(formData);
        }, 500);
    });

    device.on('hangup', (connection) => {
        this.callEndTime = new Date();
    });
}
```

Comment: the code seems ok. i belive  check your Twilio account settings are config. regarding voice capabilities and permissions. Also check for browser permission i.e web application has the necessary permissions to access the microphone and speaker of the user device

Comment: I have provided all access for the browser and configured all settings in Twilio, when I check the console of the browser, it gives me an error ie. [2024-02-18T11:38:09.833Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'.
[2024-02-18T11:38:09.832Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Disconnecting.
twilio.min.js:6660 WebSocket connection to 'wss://chunderw-vpc-gll.twilio.com/signal' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Comment: also when I check in the Twilio console for the error log it gives me the below error.
32014 - Call is terminated because of no audio received